# Hardening AWS EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-ecs, ec2-ami, hardening

I have launched and AWS ECS cluster with 4 EC2 instances with ecs optimized AMI 2 years ago, the system was working fine but due to systems hardening compliance , I need to update my ECS cluster EC2 instances with latest ECS optimized AMI.

I can take latest AMI and update the instances but how can I automate this process continously, lets say for every 3 months, My autoscaling group should update the instances with latest ECS optimized AMI release by amazon.

My EC2 instances are in autoscaling group, what **automation ideas I can implement here**.

any AWS doc or github repo link to achieve this also will be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: You can use latest ami ids from AWS System Manager's paramstore and set up [notifications when it is changed using EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-cwe.html)
Step 2: Write a lamba to update your launch config which has ami ids